# My table won't show the border i defined in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to edit the borders of my table in css but the border's won't show.
Here's the code :

```css
.midden {
  text-align: center;
}
.lijstje {
  list-style: inside;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 40%;
}
.naamkolom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top: 2px chartreuse;
}
table {
  border: 25px green;
}
body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="midden">Italiaanse Recepten</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="naamkolom">Recepten</td>
    <td class="naamkolom">Ingrediënten</td>
    <td class="naamkolom">Bereiding</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Spaghetti carbonara met andijvie</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>300 g spaghetti</li>
        <li>250 g champignons</li>
        <li>100 g Parmezaanse kaas</li>
        <li>300 g gerookte spekreepjes</li>
        <li>400 g gesneden andijvie</li>
        <li>3 eieren</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ol>
        <li>Kook de spaghetti volgens de aanwijzingen op de verpakking.</li>
        <li>Snijd ondertussen de champignons in plakjes. Rasp de Parmezaanse kaas.</li>
        <li>Verwarm een ruime hapjespan zonder olie of boter en bak de spekjes 3 min. op middelhoog vuur. Voeg de champignons en de andijvie in delen toe en bak nog 5 min. Schep regelmatig om. Breng op smaak met peper en eventueel zout.</li>
        <li>Doe ondertussen de eieren in een kom en klop met 2/3 van de kaas los tot saus.</li>
        <li>Giet de spaghetti af en doe terug in de pan. Voeg al roerend de saus toe. Blijf roeren tot de saus iets is ingedikt. Schep het andijviemengsel erdoor. Verdeel over de 4 borden en bestrooi met de rest van de kaas.</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pangrattato</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>ciabatta</li>
        <li>75 ml olijfolie</li>
        <li>2 tl chilivlokken (molentje)</li>
        <li>2 tenen knoflook</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ol>
        <li>Maal de ciabatta in de keukenmachine tot broodkruim</li>
        <li>Verhit de olijfolie in een grote koekenpan.</li>
        <li>Voeg het broodkruim en de chilivlokken, peper en eventueel zout toe en bak in 5 min. op middelhoog vuur krokant.</li>
        <li>Schep regelmatig om. Snijd ondertussen de knoflook fijn. Voeg de knoflook aan de pan toe en bak 2 min. mee op laag vuur.</li>
        <li>Neem de pan van het vuur en laat de pangrattato afkoelen.</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="Huiswerk.html">Terug naar startpagina</a>
```

I really don't understand why the border isn't showing, since i can get the top columns to change color and the title to center, so the css file is working.
I've also tried creating a selective class for the table and assigning that in the html file but that didn't work either.

Comment: try this `border: 25px solid green;`

Comment: need `solid` in your border and a `<thead>`, `<tbody>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table {
    border: 25px solid green;
}
```

instead of

```
table {
    border: 25px green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the type of border, so in your case I guess you want a `solid` border.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) you have all css types of borders